# NodeJS - Converting event.headers to lowercase for use with AWS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, testing, http-headers

Is there any way by which I can convert the event.headers to lowercase?

I came across [this thread](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2765) but I can't get it to work correctly..

**index.js**

```
// I have tried 2 different attempts, one is my own and most probably wrong, 
// the other is from the link I posted above.

// My obviously flawed attempt
function makeLower(headers) {
    for(const key in headers) {
      event.headers[key] = key.toLowerCase();
    }
  }

  // console.log('Distribution Audit Create Invoked');

  const headers = makeLower(event.headers);

  // Convert headers to lower case so AWS doesn't kick off
  // Source: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2765
  // const headers = {};
  // for (const key in event.headers) {
  //   headers[key.toLowerCase()] = event.headers[key];
  // }
  // event.headers = headers;

  console.log('HEADERS: ' + headers['content-type']);
```

**index.test.js** (testing isn't my strongest suit :-/)

```
it('should still return 202, with uppercase headers > 
     converting them to lower', done => {

    // Isn't working when sending in CAPS - Does work with non-caps
    event.headers = {'content-type': 'SOME HEADERS'};

    lambda.handler(event, null, (err, request) => {
      should.not.exist(err);
      should.exist(request);
      done();
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your function convert both the keys and the values to lowercase?

```
function makeLower(headers) {
  let head = {}

  for(const key in headers) {
    if (headers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      head[key.toLowerCase()] = headers[key].toLowerCase()
    }
  }

  return head
}
```

And not use the original object to store the lowercase values? Otherwise you end up with both the lowercase and original version in your object.

Comment: Aha, it works! Thanks for the guidance Erik. I knew I was missing something off somewhere. It was only the keys being brought back by AWS, but I can still use what you have said in future :-)

Comment: Http headers names are case insensitive - and for http2 the spec says they should be lowercase - so lowercasing the key makes sense. But http header values are definitely case sensitive and you should definitely not lowercase those.

Comment: Not what OP asked!